# How to encode and decode a jpeg file?

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, jpeg, decoding

i want to encode and decode a jpg file in a windows app with C#.

How can I do it this?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "encode and decode a jpg file"? Do you mean encrypt? Do you mean convert? Do you mean create/load/save?

Comment: use JpegBitmapDecoder / JpegBitmapEncoder

Answer (score 6):

[System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f.aspx) will load and save JPG files.

If you're using WPF, you can use the [JpegBitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.jpegbitmapencoder.aspx) and [JpegBitmapDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.jpegbitmapdecoder.aspx) classes to encode and decode JPG files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class. It can read and write JPEG, PNG and BMP files.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by encode/decode? If you have the pixels you could just use the [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class, which supports both BMP and JPEG.

Note that you will have to add a reference to `System.Drawing` to your project to use `Bitmap`.